# Meaning of "y = df['something'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x== 'yes' else 0)"

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

This Syntax is the second line after uploading a csv file by pandas library and get_dummies drop,
i want to understand this syntax better in order to make use of it
thank !

```
y = df['something'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x== 'yes' else 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code means:

```
 y = df['something'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x== 'yes' else 0)
```

Test values in column `something` and return 1 if match `yes` else return 0 in new `Series` in variable `y`.

Btw, vectorized solution is:

```
 #return Series
 y = (df['something'] == 'yes').astype(int)

 #return 1d array
 y = np.where(df['something']== 'yes', 1, 0)
```